# GIT or SVN Comment Appending to File After Commit or Vice Versa

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I am curious if it is possible either in GIT (or Mercurial) or SVN to append your comments from the commit comment.  For example, if i have a file ABC.cpp and do a Commit -m "hello world", at the end of the ABC.cpp file, it will have the commit comment append to it?  Or vice versa?  EG: Have GIT or SVN look at a tag value in near the end of the ABC.cpp code and append that as a commit comment?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Still **yes**, you *can try to get it* in Git/Mercurial, but  Greg anyway is right - it's bad manners today.

Just hints, not ready-to-use solutions

- in case of Git

> you can write your own filters for doing substitutions in files on
>   commit/checkout. These are the “clean” and “smudge” filters. In the
>   .gitattributes file, you can set a filter for particular paths and
>   then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re
>   checked out (“smudge”, see Figure 7-2) and just before they’re
>   committed (“clean”, see Figure 7-3)

([Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html), "Keywords expansion" section).

- in case of Mercurial, Keywords extension and <strike>carefully designed keyword, which catch commit-message</strike>

  [keywordmaps]
  ...
  Commitmess = {desc}

in .hgrc, which will allow you to use $Commitmess$ in sources

Answer (score 1):

No, this is something that used to be done in the CVS days (and earlier) but it's generally regarded as poor practice today. The main problem is that it makes merging *very* difficult, because *every* change to the file automatically conflicts with every other change.

Comment: "every change to the file automatically conflicts with every other change" - wrong. Filters in Git, AFAIK, modify **only presentation layer**, not storage, and **keywords content changes** in Mercurial are **not tracked**

Comment: @LazyBadger: Sure, if you want to add an additional layer on top of your VCS that hides the actual content, feel free. However, embedding the commit log inside file contents is still a bad idea.

Comment: @hewgill "embedding the commit log inside file contents is still a bad idea" - yes, I said *nothing* against **this**. In case of log-message I'll consider it as almost useless. But - if somebody wants to use, he *can use* it and should be warned about the real, not mythical, problems

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite examples of why this is bad came at a CVS site. In CVS, if you put "$Log$" in your file, it puts the commit comment in the line right after that line. It's like putting the output of "cvs log" in your commit.

Some bright person put in as the commit comment "Added $Log$ line in file". Thus, right below the commit comment was the line:

```
Added $Log$ line in the file
```

In the next commit, both instances of `$Log` caused the commit comment to be repeated. And, since one of those comments contained "$Log", we now had four instances of "$Log$".

Every time a commit was made, we ended up doubling the amount of lines in the $Log$ entry. Removing the extraneous $Log$ lines didn't help because the next commit put them back in and doubled them again.

In the end, I had to edit the `,v` file in the repository to wipe out the whole $Log$ mess.

In the Subversion documentation, they make their feelings about $Log$ [very clear](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#log-in-source).

Comment: It seems that they fixed it, At least I couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @Rudi - You're talking about CVS and not Subversion? Right?

Comment: Of course. Since I'm the one responsible to keep our company CVS server running(*grml*), I always check when I find some sings of another annoying behavior of CVS.

Comment: @Rudi - Damn, I can't get CVS in our system to do keyword substitutions at all. We're moving from CVS to SVN.

Comment: CVS Keywords can be disabled either in the CVSROOT/config file (with the` KeywordExpand` option) or by setting the -kb substitution for a file. The later one is stored in a `expand  @b@;` line (the b might be some other character/string) in the `file.name,v` file on the server.

Comment: Okay, it's probably in the config file because the status of the file is "kv". I'll have to check that. BTW this is worse than regular CVS. This is cvsnt.

Comment: Here I had to compile a 1.11 version, since the CVS version on the debian server was to new to handle our modules file.